# Why is SSHD ChallengeResponseAuthentication enabled by default?

Tags: ssh

From:

https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChallengeResponseAuthentication

> ChallengeResponseAuthentication: Specifies whether challenge-response
>   authentication is allowed. All authentication styles from
>   login.conf(5) are supported. The default is yes.

The "ChallengeResponseAuthentication" isn't used by default by any authentication. Prove me wrong.

**The question?:** Then why is this by default "yes"? It just makes a bigger attack vector!

Comment: Sounds more like a question for the openssh developers. My Fedora workstations sets this to no by default. I suspect there is a legacy compatibility reason.

Comment: Some distros having it as "no" for security reasons. I just don't get it, why the OpenBSD devs doesn't set this to "no". It would reduce the attack vector, since not all distros or usage of sshd is turning off this.